# MIPS : How to split a string from the middle?

Tags: string, split, mips

For example, I have a string `str = "I Love MIPS"`. How can I split this string from the middle length?

Should I use an array to store each character and store one half to one reg and other half to another reg?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I could not do remarkable progress. I've only calculated the length of the string :) @manetsus

Comment: While asking anything in Stackoverflow, add in your question whatever you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. Any help?

Comment: In addition to no attempt, the desired behavior isn't specified. What sort of form do you expect the output in? Can you modify the original in-place? The general approach is to walk the string halfway, copying the first half to some other memory location, then walk the second half and copy that to a different memory location.

Answer (score -1):

You have to load the address of the string with an offset into one of your registers

```
.data 
    string: .asciiz "I Love MIPS    

.text

.globl main main

la $t0 string

OFFSET:

addi $t1 $t0 8 #store string address with a 8 bit offset in $t1 => "L"
lw $t3 ($t1) # load "L"
```